# If not parent object, what does GC clear up on the parent after super.finalize() method?

Tags: java, inheritance, garbage-collection, jvisualvm

My question is based on the fact that:

- Whenever we create a sub class, the superclass object is not created even if the super class constructor is invoked.
- If finalize() method is defined in subclass then super.finalize() must be called also.

That's all well and good. But When I use the `jvisualjvm` (under the **/bin directory of the JDK installation** - I do not see any super class object instance created and that is as I expect. Superclass object is not created when we create its subclass instance.

> My question: What does GC clear up on part of the super class?

If you double click and open the `jvisualjvm`, you can see (if you halt your program with a `Thread.sleep(forEnoughTimeToCheck_jvisualjvm)` )...you will not find the super class instance there, only the subclass...probably just the reference. So does the GC clears up the super class reference whenever it does?

> I have seen many many blogs and posts on SO but I haven't seen any of
>   them explain what GC clears up on part of super class.

Comment: I don't know if this is part of your confusion or not, but it might be: when you instantiate a subclass, there is no "superclass object".  It doesn't exist.  Those parts of the superclass that are relevant to the subclass are part of the single object that is created by instantiating the subclass, and that object is of the type of the subclass.

Comment: Yes something like that, I guess my question is about the way it has been designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does the GC clears up the super class reference whenever it does?

There's no such thing as a reference to a superclass instance. With two classes like

```
class Super {
    int a;
}

class Sub extends Super {
    int b;
}
```

and `new Sub()` you get an object containing fields `a` and `b`. All these superclass stuff is interesting only in some places, like accessing `sub.a` or `instanceof` checks.

> Whenever we create a sub class, the superclass object is not created even if the super class constructor is invoked.

Yes.... a call like `new Sub()` does three things:

- it allocates space for an object big enough to hold two `int`s
- it initializes a part of it by calling the code of `Super#Super`
- it initializes a part of it by calling the code of `Sub#Super`

The call to `super()` as contained or implied in the `Sub` constructor body does no allocation at all, just the initialization.

---

The GC doesn't care at all. All it needs is to know where are references to other objects (nowhere in my example as there are just primitive fields).

> If finalize() method is defined in subclass then super.finalize() must be called also.

`finalize` is a special method which gets special handling, but again, if `Sub#finalize` overrides `Super#finalize`, then the latter becomes irrelevant (unless explicitly called from the former, which it *should* be, but that's another story).

Note that `finalize` gets used very rarely, maybe for one object in million. You shouldn't override it, unless you know that you really need it. It's not what the GC is based on.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing (except internal state as with every garbage collection phase), but because a sub-class is-a instance of it's super-class the finalizer is typically chained (just like the constructor implicitly calls `super` and the `toString` does as well). Any resources the `super` class might hold should be `free`'d and garbage collected as well.